# Implement a like function within a context menu in Java android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, interface

I have created an interface with three functions click, like, and delete. I am trying to figure out the best way to approach the like method and how to implement it. Any suggestions? Would I have to make a database reference in Firebase to store likes etc. or can I do it in the device's local memory? Any help would be great. Below is my Adapter & snippet of my MainActivity where I am attempting to place all the like code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Upload> uploads;// a list containing content from Uploads class to do this we need constructor
    private OnItemClickListener Listener;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        this.context = context;
        this.uploads = uploads;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//pass in layout of cards to populate uploads
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {//get data out of our uploads
        Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
      
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {


        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//ImageViewHolder will now handle click events within its constructor
           
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//we can now handle click events on our itemView using this constructor and we want to pass
            //these clicks back over its interface with position.
            if (Listener != null){
                int position = getAdapterPosition();//grabs position of the clicked item
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION);{//this makes sure the click position is still valid
                    Listener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
            MenuItem like = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Like");
            MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

            like.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (Listener != null){
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION);{

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case 1:
                            Listener.onLikeClick(position);
                            return true;

                        case 2:
                            Listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
//implement LikeClick in mainactivity page
    public interface OnItemClickListener{

        void onItemClick(int position);//handles general clicks

        void onLikeClick(int position);//handles like clicks

        void onDeleteClick(int position);//handles delete clicks
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){//we have set the activity as a listener for our interface
        Listener = listener;
    }

}
//this method is used to set activity for our interface
    //Listener = listener sets activity as the Listener for interface
 @Override
    public void onLikeClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Like" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
    }
//within this function edit it to start generating likes.
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Everything works i am not sure how to implement the logic behind a favourite button within a context menu

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the inteface in your main activity and on click to call other method to update the likes etc. and about saving you could go both ways depending on the app you are building.

Comment: In terms of the logic behind my onLikeClick method would i create a new firebase reference inside there to store all the favourites then link it to a new adapter for another recycler view to display the likes etc.

Comment: You can do the firebase as you want but I recomend you organizing the way that you can access more things without suffering :). Please upvote my answer if you find my answer usefull.